# SQL view with calculated column type becomes nullable

Tags: sql, view

I have got a sql table view where one of the columns is calculated: `0.1 * [column_name]`  where `[column_name]` is of type `Decimal` not `NULL`.

Received view field becomes `Decimal NULL` because of some reason.

Why `NOT NULL` changes to `NULL`?

Regards
Mariusz

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: Was going to post the code but it is no point now. below is nice example what I was talking about. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force it back to being not null by wrapping it in an ISNULL:

```
create table T (
    Value decimal(38,12) not null
)
go
create view V1
as
    select 0.1 * Value as Value from T
go
create view V2
as
    select ISNULL(0.1 * Value,0) as Value from T
go
```

V1's value column is marked as nullable, V2's isn't. Strangely, this is one place where you can't use the more standards compliant `COALESCE`:

```
create view V3
as
    select COALESCE(0.1 * Value,0) as Value from T
go
```

V3 resembles V1.

Comment: An odd case I came across when having this exact same issue with a DateTime column - when using ISNULL with GETDATE as the default value the DBML still generated a nullable datetime. I replaced GETDATE with a static date string and it then worked.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to post your code, but it's probably because a left or right join found no matching row...

Comment: Thanks for an answer but it was an issue with precisions explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx